# Interfacing Matlab with a NI real time target (cRIO 9073)

Tags: sensor, ethernet, control-system, matlab

I currently have a control system implemented in Matlab that controls a vehicle. The tracking is performed using an overhead camera, and commands are sent to the vehicle via xbee. I have now added a sensor to the vehicle that interfaces with a National Instruments real-time target (cRIO 9073) and sends measurements to the host computer's virtual instrument over ethernet. I would like to access those measurements from Matlab (running in that same computer) so that I can include them in my control algorithm.

How should I go about doing this? Moving the entire control loop to LabView isn't really an option at this point. Do you have any experience with such a set-up?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! It doesn't seem like your question is about electronic design. I'm going to recommend that it be migrated to a more appropriate site.

Comment: OK, thank you! I wasn't very sure on where to ask it but I thought EE would be a good place :)

Comment: I'd say it's quite on topic: it's a software-related question, but it fits better EE's skills than programmers', IMO.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar to this by exporting from MATLAB into VHDL code, then compiling that into an FPGA configuration. You can also export C code, which we do for controller code, and then compile that so it runs under an RTOS.

Not sure of the exact toolkits you need to have in order to make this work, as I recall they were pretty expen$ive.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think that would work: Matlab is running a control loop that interfaces with a camera (over USB) and an xbee module (over usb/serial) - all running on the host computer.